# How to iterate textfield keys with Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, textfield

I am trying to iterate through a list of students so that I can display their name in a textfield.
This is the code that I'm using in my jsp file:

```
<s:iterator value="studentList">
<s:textfield name="firstName+' '+lastName"
            cssClass="inputm" 
            disabled="true"
            id="studentsId" 
            key="Student"/>
</s:iterator>
```

This is the result that I'm getting:

Student: Ana Marrey

Student: Maria Key

Student: Eve Black

What I am trying to do is to iterate the key-Student, so that a number shows in every label, basically, I want my result to look like this:

Student 1: Ana Marrey

Student 2: Maria Key

Student 3: Eve Black

Any ideas how to add a number to my key-Student?

Comment: this is  [struts2 iterator tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html)  Introduction  <s:iterator value="studentList" id="id"   status="status"> 
index    is : <s:property value='status.index'/>

Comment: tnx for help, I found a solution, I had to use "label" instead of "key" in this case, like this: `code` label = "Student %{#status.index+1}" `code` , to get the result that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the `IteratorStatus`, and use its `index` property to achieve what you want.

From the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html)

```
<s:iterator status="status" value='{0, 1}'>
  Index: <s:property value="%{#status.index}" /> <br />
  Count: <s:property value="%{#status.count}" /> <br />  
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `status` of `<s:iterator>`

```
<s:iterator value="studentList" var="student" status="st">
     <s:property value="%{#st.index+1}"/>
<s:textfield name="firstName+' '+lastName"
            cssClass="inputm" 
            disabled="true"
            id="studentsId" 
            key="Student"/>
</s:iterator>
```